# Why does my jsp page send null when I want to bind the user input using @ModelAttribute annotation in my controller?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I am trying to bind the user input using `@ModelAttribute` annotation when the user wants to add a new book in the database (book table). 
Book class has four properties(`int bookId, String title, Author author, Publisher publisher`). User just enters the title and then select the author and publisher from drop-down lists. When the form is submitted, just title value comes to the model object in the controller and the author and publisher are null. 
I present my form and request handler method in below. Can anybody say where is the problem in my form or maybe in my controller class?

addBook.jsp

```
<form action="addBookExecution" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Enter Book's Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Select Author: </td>
    <td><select name="author">
                <option>****select author****</option>
                <c:forEach var="author" items="${authorList}">
                    <option value="${author}">${author.authorName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Select Publisher: </td>
    <td><select name="publisher">
                <option>****select publisher****</option>
                <c:forEach var="publisher" items="${publisherList}">
                    <option value="${publisher}">${publisher.publisherName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Click here to submit the form:</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="submit"/></td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addBookExecution", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView addBookExecution(@ModelAttribute Book book)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    bookService.addBook(book);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("adminFunctionsPage");
    model.addObject("Msg","Your request has been processed successfully.");
    return model;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `Spring Form`.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<form:form method="POST" commandname="book" action="addBookExecution">
  <table>
   <tr>
     <td><form:label path="title">Enter Book's Name:</form:label></td> 
     <td><form:input path="title"></form:input></td>
  </tr>
  <form:select path="author" items="${authorList}" multiple="true"/>
   -----similarly do for other html element
</form:form>
```

Comment: What should I use to display authorList and publisherList?

Comment: just updated my answer for 1 select field,do it for other also.